# Way to get an adjusted attribute table after clipping raster with polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-table, clip

I'm relatively new to ArcGIS in general, so please excuse any incorrect terminology. Currently, I am trying to clip raster data using polygons. I have clipped six of these, but the attribute table that resulted from five of them is just the attribute table for the original raster data. Strangely enough, the sixth one has adjusted values and is entirely usable. The solution I've seen for this is to re-build the attribute table, but this gets rid of attributes that I've manually added. Would anyone be able to offer advice on either what happened for that one that is correct, or otherwise on how to adjust the table without deleting my manually added attributes?

Comment: Can you tell us what version are you using? A quick google search suggest that this has been fixed after 10.1 for clip tool.
Irrespectively, this could be possible work around: Add a field in clipped raster (let's call it 'A'). Give all field unique numbers or just copy the FID. Create a copy of raster. Rebuild table for this new copy. Join the old clipped raster attribute table copy 'A' to new one.

Comment: Currently I'm using my university's 10.4.1 version. To be honest, on all the computers, the software is rather buggy. I read that it had been fixed, which is what confused me the most. I'll definitely try your suggestion the next time I get a chance. I tried something similar earlier, but got some weird results that looked like method calls in the attribute names, and they didn't copy over quite right. I'll let you know how it goes, and thank you for the suggestion!